# Выравнивание элементов flex

Tags: html, css

```css
.services {
    padding: 58px 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
    text-align: center;

}
.services-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
    text-align: center;
}

.services-block__item {
    width: 266px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 25px 15px 30px;
}
.services-block__title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #1A2940;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.services-block__subtitle {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #1A2940;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icon-web {
    font-size: 49px;
}

.icon-dev {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.icon-custom {
    font-size: 44px;
}

.icon-marketing {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="services-block">
        <div class="services-block__item">
            <span class="icon-web"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
            <span class="services-block__title">Web & App Design</span>
            <span class="services-block__subtitle">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-block">
        <div class="services-block__item">
            <span class="icon-dev"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
            <span class="services-block__title">Web & App Design</span>
            <span class="services-block__subtitle">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

в чем может быть ошибка? элементы не по горизонтали

Comment: Перенесите все flex свойства класса `.services` классу `.wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб стали по горизонтали, нужно

1. `.wrapper` указать свойство `display: flex;` или
2. `.services-block` указать свойство `display: inline-flex;`